# Fixing Broken Indexer Process: Table Truncation Safety

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, indexing

Earlier today, I had a (third party) product price indexer that consistently failed with the following message:

> "Product Prices Index process is working now. Please try run this process later."

First, I attempted to remove the lock files from /var/locks.  This did not resolve the issue.  Next, I manually truncated the following tables:

```
catalog_product_index_price
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx
catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_final_idx
catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_idx
catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx
catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_tmp
catalog_product_index_tier_price
```

This did seem to resolve the issue.

My question is this: Are there any hidden consequences of truncating these tables that might show up later?  Is this a safe operation to perform on a live database?  If so, I will be creating a tool for the project administration to use in the future.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting the Magento database repair program. Then compare your database to a good backup.